# C# restrict editing partial word paragraph

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

allow users to edit the yellow paragraph.
But I get this document:
[wrong document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G28OG.png)

I use word restrict editing feature, my code is :

```
//写入段落
foreach (TaskChaptersModel chapter in listChapter)
{
    paragraph = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
    paragraph.Range.Text = chapter.chapterNo + " " + chapter.chapterName;

    //标题1
    if (!chapter.chapterNo.Contains("."))
    {
        paragraph.Range.Font.Name = "宋体";//宋体
        paragraph.Range.Font.Bold = 2;//加粗
        paragraph.Range.Font.Size = 16;//三号
        paragraph.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;//水平居中
    }
    else if (chapter.chapterNo.Select(c => c == '.').Count() == 1)
    {
        paragraph.Range.Font.Name = "宋体";//宋体
        paragraph.Range.Font.Bold = 2;//加粗
        paragraph.Range.Font.Size = 16;//三号
        paragraph.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;//左对齐
        paragraph.Format.LineSpacingRule = Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpace1pt5;
    }
    else
    {
        paragraph.Range.Font.Name = "宋体";//宋体
        paragraph.Range.Font.Size = 12;//三号
        paragraph.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;//左对齐
        paragraph.Format.LineSpacingRule = Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpace1pt5;
    }
    paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------
    //This paragraph alow edit
    paragraph = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
    paragraph.Range.Text = "请您编辑，张三";
    paragraph.Range.Editors.Add(Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone);
    paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();                      
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------   
}

doc.Protect(Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading, false, "000", false, true);
```

My idea is to add editor at Specified paragraph.

Comment: Why can't you use [Allow changes to parts of a protected document?](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Allow-changes-to-parts-of-a-protected-document-187ed01c-8795-43e1-9fd0-c9fca419dadf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:
1、create the doc 
2、loop all paragraphs add editor at the right paragraph 
I found that I can't add editor when the doc is create.

//写入段落

```
foreach (TaskChaptersModel chapter in listChapter)
{
    if (chapter.chapterNo == null || chapter.chapterNo == "-1")
    {
        continue;
    }

    paragraph = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
    paragraph.Range.Text = chapter.chapterNo + " " + chapter.chapterName;

    //标题1
    if (!chapter.chapterNo.Contains("."))
    {
        paragraph.Range.Font.Name = "宋体";//宋体
        paragraph.Range.Font.Bold = 2;//加粗
        paragraph.Range.Font.Size = 16;//三号
        paragraph.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;//水平居中
    }
    else if (chapter.chapterNo.Select(c => c == '.').Count() == 1)
    {
        paragraph.Range.Font.Name = "宋体";//宋体
        paragraph.Range.Font.Bold = 2;//加粗
        paragraph.Range.Font.Size = 16;//三号
        paragraph.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;//左对齐
        paragraph.Format.LineSpacingRule = Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpace1pt5;
    }
    else
    {
        paragraph.Range.Font.Name = "宋体";//宋体
        paragraph.Range.Font.Size = 12;//三号
        paragraph.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphLeft;//左对齐
        paragraph.Format.LineSpacingRule = Word.WdLineSpacing.wdLineSpace1pt5;
    }

    paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
    paragraph = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add();                                     
    //有编辑权限
    if (chapter.wordFlag == "E")
    {
        paragraph.Range.Text = "请您编辑，" + userName;                        
    }
    else
    {
        paragraph.Range.HighlightColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdGray25;
    }
    paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
}

foreach (Word.Paragraph p in doc.Paragraphs)
{
    if (p.Range.Text.Contains("请您编辑"))
    {
        p.Range.Select();
        p.Range.Editors.Add(Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you got the solution

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is right to start with, however Word acts a little bit different than expected. I noticed, just like you, that however adding new paragraphs the new paragraps could be edited even though you didn't specifically added Editors to the new paragraph.

So, you need to turn it around, by adding everyone to the complete document and working the other way around by removing the editors from the parts that you want to protect.

To give you an idea I created a little piece of VBA code but I'm sure you can rewrite the parts you need in C#. Also note that I loop over the editors deleting them individually instead of using DeleteAll(). I found that using DeleteAll was throwing unexpected exceptions.

```
Sub TestRestrictDocument()

    If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
        ActiveDocument.Unprotect "000"
    End If

    ActiveDocument.Content.Editors.Add Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone

    Dim paragraph As paragraph

    For I = 1 To 5

        Set paragraph = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(I)

        If I <> 4 Then
            paragraph.Range.Select

            Dim objEditor As Editor

            If Selection.Editors.Count > 0 Then
                For X = 1 To Selection.Editors.Count
                    Selection.Editors(X).Delete
                Next
            End If
        End If

    Next

    ActiveDocument.Protect Word.WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyReading, False, "000", False, True

End Sub
```

This example shows you that (I created a document with 5 paragraphs to test) all but the fourth paragraphs can be edited. Obviously you can dynamically create your document and remove the Editors on that.

Some side notes to keep in mind that I ran into that might help:

- always check if your document is already protected
- always test if the range has Editors to delete
- Avoid DeleteAll on Editor for some reason

Comment: Sorry for late reply,
I tried you solution.I found when I open a doc, it works,When I create a doc, it still faild.
I will try more solution later.

Comment: Look careful at the solution, the demo code contains a line: [ActiveDocument.Content.Editors.Add Word.WdEditorType.wdEditorEveryone] so if you run it on an existing page the whole document gets an editor again. On existing documents you should leave that out, and only remove/add the editors on ranges you want to change.